# Iteration of model array using _.each in backbone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to iterate values using a model array instead of using collections...

JS file:

```
var Line = Backbone.Model.extend({
    attributes : {
        data:[]
    }
});

var header = new Line({data : ["Backbone JS"]});

var footer = new Line({data: ["Thank You"]});
var lowerList = new Line({data: ["Models","Collections","Views","Events","Routers"]});

var LineView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",

    render : function() {
            var self =this;
        _.each(this.model.get("data"),function(item,index){
          self.$el.append(item+"<br>");
          return item;
        });
    }
});

var headerView = new LineView({el:"#header",model: header});
headerView.render();

var footerView = new LineView({el: "#footer",model: footer});
footerView.render();

var lowerListView = new LineView({el: "#lowerList",model: lowerList});
lowerListView.render();
```

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

        <script src="js/lib/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">
        </header>
        <hr>
        <ul id="lowerList">
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <footer id="footer">
        </footer>
        <script src="js/lib/jquery-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to pass the data to the html page in a list without using the `<br>` tag in the render function

```
render : function() {
            var self =this;
        _.each(this.model.get("data"),function(item,index){
          self.$el.append(item+"<br>");
          return item;
        });
    }
```

without using `<br>` tag the output is like:

```
output:

ModelsCollectionsViewsEventsRouters
```

The values are getting iterated in the same line.
Can you suggest any way to iterate the values one by one  without using the `<br>` tag?

Comment: What do you want the final html to be? A `ul` with a `li` for each entry of `data`? Or the text spaced out, comma-separated... ?

Answer (score 0):

Since your view's `el` is a `<ul>` (`tagName: "li"` is ignored when you pass `el` option), your view should append `<li>` to it per item, something like:

```js
var LineView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    _.each(this.model.get("data"), function(item, index) {
      this.$el.append("<li>" + item + "</li>");
    }, this);
  }
});
```

---

A better option would be to use a CollectionView and an ItemView concept:

```js
var LineView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "li",
  initialize(options) {
    this.item = options.item;
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.text(item);
  }
});

var LinesView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    _.each(this.model.get("data"), function(item, index) {
      var childView = new LineView({item: item});
      this.$el.append(childView.$el);
    });
  }
});
```

Even better option would be to actually use a Backbone.Collection instance for the Collection view